# Facing a issue in selenium 4.12.0 npm package

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am able to run the same code on 4.11.1 and earlier but am not able to run on 4.12.0.

```
`if(await driver.findElement(By.id(global_elements.global.logout_btn_id)).isDisplayed())
{
await driver.switchTo().frame(global_elements.global.frame1);
await driver.findElement(By.xpath(elements_json.home.user_btn_xpath)).click();
await driver.findElement(By.id(elements_json.users.add_btn_id)).click();
}`
```

Comment: Could u please tell me more about the issue? what was the error or exception?

Comment: its throw an exception "NoSuchElementError" from "await driver.findElement(By.id(elements_json.users.add_btn_id)).click();"
this line.. and also after isDisplayed perform the web page getting stuck..

Comment: put the xpath path in a double colon."     "

Comment: I am storing all elements xpath and id in a json and from there fetching value..